# Increase the length of Xcode's "recent project" list?

Tags: xcode

I switch in Xcode between working on a lot of different projects frequently (some I'm actively working on, some are old projects where I'm looking up code I want to re-use or quote in SO answers :)), so that part of my "working set" of projects invariably ends up falling off the recent project list.    I do use finder tabs for the full working set of current project folders, but I really like the fast switching available using the recent projects list.

Is there a way to increase the length of this list so that I can see more recently opened projects?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

On a terminal window, for XCode 7 and above type the following command: (from Matteo Gaggiano):

```
defaults write com.apple.dt.Xcode NSRecentDocumentsLimit X
```

where X is the max number of projects in list.

For XCode version below 7, the following worked.

```
defaults write com.apple.Xcode NSRecentDocumentsLimit X
```

Comment: In Xcode 9 (when I'm writing, the start version should be Xcode 7) you can increase it with `defaults write com.apple.dt.Xcode NSRecentDocumentsLimit 50`

Answer (score 16):

You could change the length of the list with the number of recent items in System Preferences -> General (Appearence on older macOS versions) as well. However that will change it for all apps.

You need to restart your machine for the change to kick in.

Comment: An update: in OSX El Capitan, recent items is under System Preferences -> General

Comment: @Wasim have you tried to look in `System Preferences -> General`

Comment: Hey Mellson, it's working after I restarted my Mac :) Now I can see open recent is growing up. Thanks!

Answer (score 4):

**Do Hit Command + Spacebar   >   Type General   >   Follow the screenshot attached.**

[image: 2]]