# Xcode doesn't show recent projects in recent projects list

Tags: xcode

Every time I start Xcode it gives me a window where my recent projects supposedly should be. It would come in handy but unfortunately it's always empty.

Does it have anything to do with the location where I store my projects? I hope not.

Thanks for any help!

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5087965/increase-the-length-of-xcodes-recent-project-list/5088029#5088029 might help

Comment: The mentioned posts answer worked for me:  defaults write com.apple.Xcode NSRecentDocumentsLimit X

Answer (score 176, accepted):

I would think it's because you could have your recent items set to 0 in System Preferences -> Appearance.

**Update** - If you are using Yosemite the correct path is System Preferences -> General -> Recent items (Thanks to [@karim](https://stackoverflow.com/users/312627/karim))

**Update** - If you are using Ventura the correct path is System Preferences -> Desktop & Dock -> Recent documents, applications, and servers

EDIT: Based on comments : `Then Reboot`

Comment: this did not work for me.  i only see this issue in xcode, not other programs (preview works fine for example).  any other possibilities?

Comment: This also did not work for me. Recents works everywhere else—just not Xcode.

Comment: Yes - that was it, but how on earth was it ever changed to zero to begin with? (El Capitan)

Comment: Thanks. Mine seemed to magically set itself to zero in the last 2 days. Annoying!

Comment: In fact, when I change the setting, it won't stick! It keeps going back to None

Comment: Seeing a similar issue as Darren.

Comment: I am same as Darren, always empty Xcode recent project.

Comment: Did anyone manage to solve the issue @Darren is having? It seems it has happened in the last El Capitan update.

Comment: A reboot fixed my problem of the change not sticking.

Comment: I had no idea this preference existed. Must have reset itself at some point because I for sure never touched it. But yes, that was it, and thank you!!

Comment: Simply log out and log in again did it for me.

Answer (score 32):

@Mellson answer is correct. But there is no menu in OS X Yosemite, System Preferences -> Appearance. 
It should be, System Preferences -> General -> Recent items. Set e.g. 5 items.

or in command line,

```
defaults write com.apple.Xcode NSRecentDocumentsLimit 5
```

However, to my experience the first one works more correctly.

[image]

Comment: Xcode 7's bundle id is `com.apple.dt.Xcode`, where "dt" means development tool.

Comment: It was OK in the general preferences, so using the command line fixed it. Not sure how it got set wrong.

Comment: Used `defaults write com.apple.dt.Xcode NSRecentDocumentsLimit 50` on Xcode 9 and is ok.

Comment: For some reason it didn't work when I changed the setting through the Settings app but worked with the command. Thanks!

Answer (score 22):

**Restart** your mac.

[image]

Earlier, I faced the same issue after I did Xcode 7.3 update. It showed me empty (Clear) Xcode File -> Open Recents menu.

Comment: Now i understand why you have got less upvotes!!  I almost forgot to upvote after restarting the system :) But upvoted finally !

Comment: Worked for me, thank you for reminding us that the Restart option is still a viable solution at times :-) In my case, I had upgraded Xcode from 8.3.2 to 8.3.3 earlier, and didn't realise until much later my last reboot was over a month ago.

Answer (score 3):

You disabled the Welcome to Xcode screen. Press shift+command+1, and then reselect the checkbox as shown below. You can also start a new project from the File menu : New > Project… without the Welcome to Xcode screen.

Answer (score 0):

If you're facing the issue where Xcode doesn't show recent projects in the recent projects list, you can resolve it by using a command-line workaround. Follow these steps:

1. Open the Terminal application on your Mac. You can find it in the Applications folder or by searching for "Terminal" in Spotlight.
2. In the Terminal window, paste the following command and press Enter:

   ```
   defaults write com.apple.dt.Xcode NSRecentDocumentsLimit 10
   ```

   This command sets the limit for the number of recent projects displayed in Xcode's recent projects list to 10. You can adjust the number 10 to your preferred limit.
3. After running the command, restart Xcode for the changes to take effect. You should now see the recent projects in the list as expected.

This command adjusts the preferences for Xcode, specifically setting the limit for recent documents. By default, Xcode limits the number of recent projects displayed, and this command allows you to customize that limit to your preference.

Remember to replace "10" with the number of recent projects you want to see in the list. You can adjust this number based on your preferences.

Comment: This command allowed me to see recent projects again, thanks Ashish