# Xcode 8 Open Recent list is empty

Tags: ios, xcode

I tried adjusting this setting in system preferences:

[image]

[image]

Comment: i don't think this is an Xcode issue

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Xcode doesn't show recent projects in recent projects list](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5180100/xcode-doesnt-show-recent-projects-in-recent-projects-list)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What you can try is from terminal execute the following statement:

```
defaults write com.apple.dt.Xcode NSRecentDocumentsLimit 5
```

and then restart your Mac, that should fix it.

Cheers!

Comment: For some reason it didn't work when I changed the setting through the Settings app but worked with the above command. Thanks!